# How to find input element id by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the id of an input element based on its value? The values will always be unique and there are only seven of them. I have tried this:

```
$('#wrapper').find("input[value='"+value+"']").each(function(){
    return this.id;
});
```

But nothing is returned!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

<strike>$(this).id</strike> nope, this.id works, no need to create a jQuery object for the ID.

or

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

HTH

EDIT:
This might work:

```
$('#wrapper').find("input[value='"+value+"']").attr('id');
```

Comment: yup, you are right, have updated my answer to reflect that. Thx

Comment: now that you have corrected it, it does not, but wrong untested/information = downvote, no ?

Comment: Thats fair enough, although the answer did contain the correct info, albeit one option presented was wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You write `return this.id;`… Return where? You simply return value from anonymous functions and I don't see where you ever trying to use it. So the answer is:

```
var idYouAreSearchingFor = $('#wrapper').find("input[value='"+value+"']").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

your code is almost good:

```
$('#wrapper').find("input[value='"+value+"']").each(function(){
        return  $(this).attr("id") 
});
```

check here
http://jsfiddle.net/5xsZt/

edit: i have just tested it with `this.id` it works to. Your code is right. Your error is somewhere else: check it:
http://jsfiddle.net/5xsZt/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). Like this:

```
$('#wrapper input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == value;
}).each(function() {
    return this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that will definitely work in all mainstream browsers:

```
function getInputWithValue(wrapper, value) {
    var inputs = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var i = inputs.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (inputs[i].value === value) {
            return inputs[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var input = getInputWithValue(wrapper, "some value");
window.alert(input.id);
```